# How to detect an irrational $(x + \sqrt{\lambda})/y$ by approximation?

Tags: supremum-and-infimum, python

Let $\lambda = (1024 + \sqrt{101})/7$.

Let also $J(x, y) = |(x \lambda + y)^2 - $ round$(x \lambda + y)^2|$.

We want to deduce that $\inf J = 0$ for $(x, y) = (7, -1024) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$.

I know something with real numbers, but I want integers.

I tried periodic continued fractions (Python), but the periods are too large.

How wolfram alpha knows by the digits what is $\lambda$?

---

After that I tried the [simplex algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm), and the output was:
$14772141080301727003860275213039\,x^2 - 2182261520963378741374304192941500\,x + 14772141080301727003860275213039 = 0$

$\Delta = 4761392481269013762405900791716544060291640138310882045235079787916$

Probably, that's because I searched for rational numbers $a = 1, b \le -1, c \ge 1$.

The ideal output would be $(7x - 1024)^2 - 101 = 0$

$\Rightarrow 49x^2 - 14336x + 1048475 = 0$. How to simplify?

---

The truth is that I can't detect $\cfrac{123456}{654321}$ by the digits.

```
def detect_sqrt(original, repetition = 1e-6, remainder = 1e-9):
   vec = mp.zeros(10240, 1)
   restos = mp.zeros(10240, 1)
   s = original
   fixed = 0
   flag = False
   for counter in range(0, 10240):
      f = mp.floor(s)
      vec[counter] = f
      s = mp.fsub(s, f)
      restos[counter] = s
      if mp.fabs(s) < remainder:
         s = 0
         flag = True
         if (vec[0] == vec[counter]) and (counter > 0):
            counter = counter - 1
         break
      for i in range(0, counter):
         dif = mp.fabs(restos[i] - s)
         if dif < repetition:
            flag = True
            if (i == 0) and (vec[0] == vec[counter]):
               fixed = 0
               counter = counter - 1
            else:
               fixed = i + 1
            #print("dif =", dif)
            break
      if flag:
         break
      s = mp.fdiv(1, s)
   i = counter
   w = mp.zeros(i + 1, 1)
   for j in range(0, i + 1):
      w[j] = vec[j]
   mid = counter - fixed + 1
   if mid > 1:
      if s == 0:
         #if vec[i - 1] != 0:
            #if counter == 1:
               #print("x =", my_int(vec[i-1]), "+ 1/", my_int(vec[i]))
            #else:
               #print("a_1 =", my_int(vec[i-1]), "+ 1/", my_int(vec[i]))
         mid = mid - 1
         i = i - 1
      #else:
         #print("a_1 =", my_int(vec[i]), "+ 1/x")
      for j in range(2, mid):
         i = i - 1
         #print("a_", j, "=", my_int(vec[i]), "+ 1/a_", j - 1)
      #if mid > 1:
         #print("x =", my_int(vec[fixed]), "+ 1/a_", mid - 1)
   #elif s != 0:
      #print("x =", my_int(vec[fixed]), "+ 1/x")
   j = mid
   i = fixed - 1
   #if i == 0:
      #print("y =", my_int(vec[i]), "+ 1/x")
   #elif i != -1:
      #print("a_", j, "=", my_int(vec[i]), "+ 1/x")
      #while (i > 1):
         #i = i - 1
         #j = j + 1
         #print("a_", j, "=", my_int(vec[i]), "+ 1/a_", j - 1)
      #print("y =", my_int(vec[0]), "+ 1/a_", j)

   if s == 0:
      i = counter
      a = vec[i]
      b = 1      # a over 1
      while i > 0:
         i = i - 1
         a, b = b, a
         a = a + b * vec[i]
      #print("x =", my_int(a), "/", my_int(b))
   else:
      i = counter
      a = vec[i]
      b = 1 # ax + 1
      c = 1 # over
      d = 0 # 1x + 0
      # print(a, "x +", b, "//", c, "x +", d)
      while i > fixed:
         i = i - 1
         a, b, c, d = c, d, a, b
         a = mp.fadd(a, mp.fmul(c, vec[i]))
         b = mp.fadd(b, mp.fmul(d, vec[i]))
         # print(a, "x +", b, "//", c, "x +", d)
      #print(my_int(c), "x^2 +", my_int(d - a), "x +", my_int(-b), "= 0") # x (cx + d) = ax + b
      j, a, b, c, d = mp.fadd(power(d - a, 2), mp.fmul(4, mp.fmul(c, b))), a - d, 1, 2*c, 0
      #print("x_1 = (", my_int(a), "+", my_int(b), "sqrt(", my_int(j), "))/(", my_int(c), "+", my_int(d), "sqrt(", my_int(j), "))")
      #print("x_2 = (", my_int(a), "-", my_int(b), "sqrt(", my_int(j), "))/(", my_int(c), "+", my_int(d), "sqrt(", my_int(j), "))")
      while i > 0:
         i = i - 1
         a, b, c, d = c, d, a, b
         a = mp.fadd(a, mp.fmul(c, vec[i]))
         b = mp.fadd(b, mp.fmul(d, vec[i]))
      #if fixed != 0:
         #print("y_1 = (", my_int(a), "+", my_int(b), "sqrt(", my_int(j), "))/(", my_int(c), "+", my_int(d), "sqrt(", my_int(j), "))")
         #print("y_2 = (", my_int(a), "-", my_int(b), "sqrt(", my_int(j), "))/(", my_int(c), "-", my_int(d), "sqrt(", my_int(j), "))")
   if (fixed > 100) or (counter > 100):
      flag = False
   return flag, 1, 1, 1, 1 # a/b + c sqrt(j)
```

Comment: To answer the last question, WA most probably uses an [integer relation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_relation_algorithm). But what exactly did you ask WA?

Comment: Some Spirit told me that a simplex with $J = a\lambda^2 + b\lambda + c$ with integral solution should resolve. Define WA.

Comment: If this is True, we could determine the minimal polinomial of many other $a_n \lambda^n$.

Comment: WA = [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com)

Comment: [approximation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28147.72141080301727003860275213039+*+7+-+1024%29%5E2). I think I have to navigate into those LLL, HJLS, PSOS, PSLQ. Do you have hints?
I tried my own simplex.c with $x_+ = 2.4142135$. The solution was: $241421 x^2 - 682842 x + 241421 = 0 \Rightarrow x_- = 0.414213$. Better or worse with Python?